# Infinite Geometric Series Involving Squares

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to evaluate an expression of form

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{6^n}$$

Is there any way to generalize this for any natural number $i$?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^i}{6^n}$$

Comment: Any reason why the $2$ is being generalized to a variable and not the $6$ in the denominator?

Comment: You might want to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2 x^n$ and then evaluate for $x=\frac{1}{6}$. Also, you can generalize it for any such form. As a hint - start with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n$ and derive term by term.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^{nx}}{6^n}=\frac{e^x}{6-e^x} $$
since the LHS is a geometric series.

By differentiating $i$ times with respect to $x$, then evaluating at $x=0$, we get:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^i}{6^n} = \left.\frac{d^i}{dx^i}\left(\frac{e^x}{6-e^x}\right)\right|_{x=0} $$
that can be written in terms of [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), too, since $n^i$ can be written as a linear combination of $\binom{n}{i},\binom{n}{i-1},\ldots,\binom{n}{0}$ and:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\binom{n}{i}\frac{1}{6^n} =  \frac{6}{5^{i+1}}. $$

In the particular case $i=2$ we have:

> $$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^2}{6^n} = 2\sum_{n\geq 1}\binom{n}{2}\frac{1}{6^n}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{6^n} = \frac{12}{125}+\frac{6}{25} = \color{red}{\frac{42}{125}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The function Polylogarithm provides a large generalization :

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^r x^n = \text{Li}_{-r}(x)$$
Example :

$r=2\quad\to\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2 x^n = \text{Li}_{-2}(x)=\frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3}\qquad$ Eq.(9) in the paper cited above.

If $x=\frac{1}{6}\quad\to\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{6^n} = \text{Li}_{-2}(\frac{1}{6})=\frac{\frac{1}{6} (\frac{1}{6}+1)}{(1-\frac{1}{6})^3}=\frac{42}{125}$

Answer (score 0):

The infinite geometric series is pretty well known:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} r^i = \frac{r}{1 - r} \;\;  0 \leq r < 1$$

The next more complicated sum is known as [Gabriel's staircase](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GabrielsStaircase.html) or the Arithmetico-geometric series, and its sum is also well known:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} ir^i = \frac{r}{(1 - r)^2}$$

The term you ask about, which is $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{i^2}{6^i}$ (I just changed your variable names) is a special case of this sequence:

$$S = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^2r^i$$

Where $r = \frac16$. The first part of your question then asks is there a general [closed form] formula for such sums? The answer is yes. Using the above results we can derive such a formula:

$$S(1 - r) = S - rS = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^2r^i - \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^2r^{i+1} = \\
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^2r^i - \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} (i - 1)^2r^i = \\
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^2r^i - (i - 1)^2r^i = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} (2i - 1)r^i = \\
2\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} ir^i - \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} r^i$$

Now we've reduced to terms we already know: a geometric series plus an arithmetico-geometric series. Applying the formulas we've already seen for those:

$$ = 2\left(\frac{r}{(1 - r)^2}\right) - \frac{r}{1 - r}$$

Remember this is the term for $S(1 - r)$ so to get $S$ we divide by $1 - r$ to get:

$$S = 2\left(\frac{r}{(1 - r)^3}\right) - \frac{r}{(1 - r)^2}$$

Now we see a clear pattern, and this leads us to the second part of your question. All series we've seen so far are special cases of the following series:

$$S_{k, r} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^kr^i$$

Does a closed form formula exist for every $k$? There's good news and bad news. The good news is yes, I can prove constructively that for each $k$, there exists such a formula. However, I can't prove that there exists a single closed form formula that covers all values of $k$. Subtle difference in the quantifiers. That's not to say such a formula doesn't exist - it's just I, the author, don't know of one.

To prove the existence of a closed form formula for $S_{k, r}$, we do induction on $k$. Clearly we've already seen closed form formulas for $k = 0, 1, 2$, which is more than enough for our base case. So we only need to prove the inductive case. Take:

$$S_{k+1, r} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^{k + 1}r^i$$

We now apply the trick of multiplying by $1 - r$ and apply the binomial theorem to reduce this to a closed form expression involving sums we already know, by our inductive hypothesis.

$$S_{k+1, r}(1 - r) = S_{k+1, r} - rS_{k+1, r} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^{k+1}r^i - \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^{k+1}r^{i+1} = \\
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^{k+1}r^i - \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} (i - 1)^{k+1}r^i = \\
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} i^{k+1}r^i - (i - 1)^{k+1}r^i$$

At this point we notice that by expanding the second term via the binomial expansion, the two powers of $i^{k+1}r^i$ cancel each other out:

$$ = - \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{j = 1}^{k+1} {k + 1 \choose j} (-1)^j i^{k + 1 - j}r^i
$$

And since summation order can be interchanged:

$$ = - \sum_{j = 1}^{k+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} {k + 1 \choose j} (-1)^j i^{k + 1 - j}r^i
$$

But we can remove from the inner sum any constant w.r.t. the variable $i$ so:

$$ = - \sum_{j = 1}^{k+1}{k + 1 \choose j} (-1)^j\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}  i^{k + 1 - j}r^i \\
= - \sum_{j = 1}^{k+1}{k + 1 \choose j} (-1)^jS_{k + 1 - j,r}
$$

But remember this was the term for $S_{k+1, r}(1 - r)$ so we have:

$$S_{k+1, r} = \frac{-1}{1 - r}\sum_{j = 1}^{k+1}{k + 1 \choose j} (-1)^jS_{k + 1 - j,r}$$

By our inductive hypothesis since each $S_{k + 1 - j,r}$ has a closed form expression, then the above is a closed form expression for any given $k$.